# If a sequnce $(a_n)_n \to L$, $(\sqrt{a_n})_n \to \sqrt L$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

How do you prove the following:

> If a sequnce $(a_n)_n \to L$, $(\sqrt{a_n})_n \to \sqrt L$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L}|= |\frac {(\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L})(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L})} {\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}}|=|\frac{a_n-L}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}}|$$

Now, $\sqrt{x} \geq 0$, so, $\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}\geq\sqrt{L}$ hence, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$

So, $$|\frac{a_n-L}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}}| \leq |\frac{a_n-L}{\sqrt{L}}|$$ Which goes to $0$ since $a_n$ goes to L.

Comment: Can you explain the last sentence please?

Comment: Your hypothesis was that $(a_n)_n \longrightarrow L$, so $|a_n-L|$ tends to $0$ for large $n$. Hence, in the last line we bound $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L}|$ from above by a value that tends to $0$ for large $n$. So, $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L}|$ must tend to $0$, hence $\sqrt{a_n} \longrightarrow \sqrt{L}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $x,y\geq 0$:
$$
|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq \sqrt{|x-y|}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint: $a_n-L = (\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt L)(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt L)$

Answer (score 1):

For $L>0$
Fix $\varepsilon >0$. From definition of limit there is $n$, such that $\| a_n - L \|<\sqrt{L} \varepsilon$.
Therefore
$\|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L} \| = \|\frac{a_n-L}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}}\|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \| a_n - L \| < \varepsilon$

If $L=0$ then we have to take $n$, such that $\| a_n - L \|< \varepsilon ^2 $